# "Konnte ... worden" oder "konnte ... werden"?

Tags: grammaticality

Ich las gerade diesen Satz:

> Durch unsere endodontische Arbeit konnten über 2000 Zähne erhalten worden.

Sollte das nicht eigentlich

> Durch unsere endodontische Arbeit konnten über 2000 Zähne erhalten **werden**.

sein?

---

(*Ich bin Niederländer und normalerweise ziemlich firm in solchen Sachen, aber manchmal bin ich mir nicht sicher, ob meine Meinung nicht ein "Hollandizismus" ist*.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Richtig ist:

> Durch unsere endodontische Arbeit konnten über 2000 Zähne erhalten werden.

Comment: Also wie ich schon dachte. Danke.